# Using Asp.Net, can an button, asp or html, be bound directly to an Access database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have looked at many examples and articles on binding controls to a database, but all of them deal with lists and GridViews.  I have tried porting those methods over to an asp button but not successfully.  I can not find any method of attaching a DataSource to the button such as,

```
Partial Class Rum
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Button61.DataSource = "x"

End Sub
```

I am using VB.Net and willing to use it or jQuery to accomplish this.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What property of the button do you want to come from the database?

Comment: I am trying to get both BackColor and Text

Comment: Just write some code to do it. "Button61" could do with a meaningful name to make your job easier, which I suspect applies to buttons 1 through 60 also ;) . Please note that Access is not often a good choice for ASP.NET applications - SQL Server Express is free and works *reliably* for simultaneous users.